# Transparent Panel with no artifacts

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, alpha-transparency

I've very limited knowledge with overriding `JComponent` objects and painting in Java. What I'm trying to do is to create a function that I can call to set the transparency and avoid getting artifacts when buttons are clicked inside a panel. Basically I'm gonna be using this on a `JPanel` inside another panel. Like,

```
class panel1 extends JPanel(){
public panel1(){
    this.add(new panel2())
    //call the setPanelTransparency(this);
}

class panel2 extends JPanel(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(2,Color.RED);
}
```

How do I correct this method? I get errors when I tried to include it as method in `panel1` class.

```
 public void setPanelTransparency(JPanel myPanel){

    protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
    {
        g.setColor ( getBackground () );
        g.fillRect ( 0, 0, getWidth (), getHeight () );
        super.paintComponent ( g );
    }

    });
    myPanel.setOpaque(false);
    myPanel.setBackground(new Color(49,43,31,60));
}
```

I'd appreciate any help. I would just like to know the simplest way to make Panels transparent without any risk of artifacts. I need a method that I can call. Also, I tried `UIManager.put()` but doesn't seem to apply properly without any artifacts.

I'd appreciate the simplest solution to applying transparency to my project so I can focus on creating the tables.

Comment: You can't define a method in a method. Please post compilable code. Also please describe what kind of artifacts you are referring to. Non-transparent pixles? Flickering? And finally: what do you need that for? Is it really necessary to do painting yourself?

Comment: *"I'd appreciate the simplest solution to applying transparency to my project so I can focus on creating the tables."* Sounds like putting look before functionality. The other way around will result in a better app.

Comment: @Thomas, `Is it really necessary to do painting yourself?` - yes it is when dealing with transparent backgrounds because Swing does not support this properly. Check out the link in my answer for more information on this topic.

Comment: Hmm, I think I expressed myself in the wrong way. Yes, it's necessary to paint yourself if you want to have transparency, what I was getting at is what Andrew commented: is it really necessary to have transparency? Btw have a look at the SwingX components, maybe those help with what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a method like setPanelTransparency() to override a method.

That panel needs to be a class on its own to override the paintComponent(...) method:

```
//public void setPanelTransparency(JPanel myPanel){
public class TransparentPanel extend JPanel 
{
    TransparentPanel()
    {
        setOpaque( false );
    }

    @Override
    protectect void paintComponent(...)
    ...
}
```

Then you just use the panel like:

```
TransparentPanel panel = new TransparentPanel();
panel.setBackground(...);
panel.add( new JTestField(10) );
frame.add( panel );
```

See [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information on this approach and a different solution.

Comment: thank you very much. I was also  reading about custom painting in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ and the problem I had when i asked this was how to override and where the position the block to contain the overridden painComponent. I've managed to apply the transparency with no artifacts with your help. I very much appreciate the idea. :-) I'm also reading the blog you sent for additional details.